# Filling POCO Object with List inside a List

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I´m attempting to fill a POCO object but I get the NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object, at line "***objectAreas.position.Add(objectPositions);***" I think I'm not initializing well but I don't see my mistake, let's see the code:

**POCO OBJECT**

```
public class GenericQuery
{
    public sealed class Areas
    {
        public int idarea { get; set; }
        public string areaname { get; set; }
        public List<Positions> positions { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Positions
    {
        public int idposition { get; set; }
        public string positionname { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class QueryAreasPositions
    {
        public int code { get; set; }
        public string response { get; set; }
        public List<Areas> areas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

**Filling It**

```
GenericQuery.QueryAreasPositions objectAreasPositions = new GenericQuery.QueryAreasPositions();

var query = areaRepository.Get(); //Eager Loading EntityFramework List Object, see the AreaRepository at the end

objectAreasPositions.code = 123;
objectAreasPositions.response = "anything";

foreach (var area in query)
    {
        GenericQuery.Areas objectAreas = new GenericQuery.Areas();
        objectAreas.idarea = area.IdArea;
        objectAreas.areaname = area.Name;
            foreach (var position in area.Position)
            {
                GenericQuery.Positions objectPositions = new GenericQuery.Positions();
                objectPositions.idposition = position.IdPosition;
                objectPositions.positionname = position.Name;
                ***objectAreas.position.Add(objectPositions);***//HERE
            }

        objectAreasPositions.areas.Add(objectAreas); //And maybe here
     }
```

**AreaRepository**

```
public List<Area> Get()
{
    using (var context = new Entities())
    {
        return context.Area.Include("Position").ToList();
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help/guide you can give me, Thanks.

Comment: objectAreas.position= new List<Position>();

Comment: @Gusman, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never initializing `objectAreas.position`, hence the default value for a `List<T>` is `null`.

Since you are trying to call the `Add` method on a `null` reference, you are getting a **NullReferenceException**.

To fix this, you should initialize the property before using it:

```
objectAreas.position = new List<GenericQuery.Positions>();
```

**Alternatively**, you can add this logic on `GenericQuery.Areas` constructor, which would be more appropriate:

```
public sealed class Areas
{
    public int idarea { get; set; }
    public string areaname { get; set; }
    public List<Positions> positions { get; set; }

    public class Areas()
    {
         positions = new List<Positions>();
    }
}
```

Comment: the constructor option works perfect, I take it, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you rather be doing like below. Your `position` is `null` cause not yet initialized and thus the said exception.

```
objectAreas.position = new List<Position>();
objectAreas.position.Add(objectPositions);
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see my mistake.